# Port forwarding very strange behavior

Tags: port-forwarding

I have a web server at my home which is configured to be accessed from outside through public ip on port 8081.  E.g.  http://public ip:8081 .   I have my laptop which connects to my home network and if I try to use the above http://public ip:8081 the website works.    But one of my desktop which is also connected to my home network suddenly stopped working after a router change weeks ago.   The comcast router has port forwarding enabled for port 8081 to go to the web server.   I even disabled firewall completely on desktop, and the server itself and comcast router and still only the laptop is able to reach the http web services from inside the network.   But the desktop cannot.   I can ping the public ip from the desktop and it would respond. But the http://public ip:8081 throws the following error as if it can't access that port at all:

This site can’t be reached "public ip"  took too long to respond.
Try:

Checking the connection
Checking the proxy and the firewall
Running Windows Network Diagnostics
ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT

So I've tried everything.   So the most confusing part is why is the laptop able to see the web services , but the desktop can't.     I even did a "route print" on both desktop and laptop to see what's going on and the routing table is very similar.   But I can ping the public ip from the desktop but not the website through http://public ip:8081.  Is there any utility that can trace this?  tracert doesn't show anything except one hop to the comcast router on both laptop and desktop.

Comment: Ping doesn't run on HTTP, it uses ICMP protocol. It's not possible to ping IPADDRESS:PORT; that's not how ICMP works. And a firewall is very likely to drop ping from the router WAN side anyway; for good reasons. First thing to do - verify that your web server actually has the same IP address you have configured in the port forwarding. please don't answer in a comment, update your question with new testing and results; and any other new info.

Comment: The webserver ip is fine.   Because I'm able to connect to the webserver from my laptop, but not from the desktop as mentioned in the original post.   Both laptop and desktop are in the same network.    Only difference is the desktop is hard wired.   Laptop is through wifi.   I'm currently checking if there's an issue with the smart switch by any chance

Comment: I'm not brushing you off, mate :-) But again, please update your question with new info. Remember you ain't talking to a tech support where you get a person helping you. Updating your question keeps all the necessary info on your setup in one place so anyone in the community can see your situation in one place without going through commentaries. Examples of new info here: desktop wired, laptop through wi-fi; there's a smart switch somewhere... in this case a simple topology map showing the connectivity might also be helpful.

Comment: When you're trying to access your webserver _within_ your network `http://public.ip:8081` isn't likely to work. Public IP is for connecting over the internet. Inside your intra you need to `http://private.ip:8081`. Different routers might behave differently, so knowing models could be helpful. The devil's in the details - the more you give, the better you can be helped.